# Font errors when rendering some pdf files with quartz on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, fonts, quartz-2d

We have been using quartz to render pdf files in our apps for more than 2 years, and have not had real problems so far.

However, one of our customers recently reported that some fonts were not correctly displayed on some of their pdf files.

The problem occurs only on iOS: the pdf files are rendered correctly on Mac (with Adobe reader or even Preview) and PC **(with Adobe Reader)**.

Further more, we have checked the file in Acrobat Pro using Preflight, and the fonts are not missing.

Here is the error messages that we get on Xcode when displaying one of the files:

```
Nov 13 18:41:49 anonymized[1192] <Error>: FT_Open_Face failed: error 2.

FAILED to create agar for HelveticaLTMM.

FAILED to create agar for TimesLTMM.

Nov 13 18:41:49 anonymized[1192] <Error>: FT_Open_Face failed: error 2.

Nov 13 18:41:49 anonymized[1192] <Error>: FT_Open_Face failed: error 2.
```

Any suggestions for this? Many thanks.

Comment: are you able to find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS only has Helvetica and Times, not HelveticaLTMM or TimesLTMM.  But the computer running Preflight may have had those fonts installed, so had no problem there.

Or the desktop is able to figure out the font family even with the "TMM" suffix and the iOS is not.

(Unless you supply this font inside your app.)

Comment: So if I remove HelveticaLTMM fonts while creating PDF file...it will resolve my issue !! ??

Comment: You should not have to remove those fonts from the desktop.  Just don't use them in the file used to create the PDF.  Stick to the fonts available on iOS, Mac and Windows.